# SMS gateways for iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application for iPhone which need to send an SMS message to mutiple users at a time .Is there any third party solution to do this.Is there anyone previously done this.Looking for a solution.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the standard mechanism (i.e. MFMessageComposeViewController) to send SMS messages to multiple recipients. The `recipients` property is an NSArray object.

Answer (score -1):

What about an HTTP to SMS service. In the UK I have used http://www.textanywhere.net/  although I am sure there will be many, many others providing this service now.